# How to make the JQuery News Ticker responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have designed a [website](http://gymkhana.iitb.ac.in/~hostel3/) using Bootstrap 3.0. I'm using the [jQuery News Ticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/) for feed which I am providing through HTML (and not through the server).

This is what I have done to include the Ticker:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
                <li class="news-item">News1</li>
                <li class="news-item">News2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

For some reason, this ticker isn't responsive like the rest of the webpage.

One way it can be done is through media queries. But is there a way to do this using Bootstrap (or simple css)?

Comment: https://github.com/rhodimus/jQuery-News-Ticker/issues/19 discussion about making ticker responsive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add this 2 lines in somewhere in your CSS

```
.ticker-wrapper,
.ticker-wrapper .ticker{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```